# Issue with SQL "Order by"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I would like to compose a SQL query that for example selects the top 2 values of a sorted table using `ORDER BY` with a query below, but I'm getting unexpected results

```
 select top 2 * from (select top 100 percent * from events order by dates desc) a ;
```

let's say for example, if the values of the table were  1,3,4

using

```
 select top 100 percent * from events order by dates desc;
```

would give me 4,3,1

but with

```
 select top 2 * from (select top 100 percent * from events order by dates desc) a;
```

I get 1,3 instead of 4,3

I was wondering why is that the case and am I missing something?

Comment: Your `ORDER BY` is only affecting the subquery. The outer query does not specify an `ORDER BY` and therefore the optimizer is allowed to use *any* order at all.

Comment: using TOP without ORDER BY has no meaning. You will need to use ORDER BY on the outer query as well

Comment: the inner query `TOP 100 percent` and `order by dates desc` are actually redundant. Basically it is same as `select * from events`

Answer (score 0):

use order by in outer query as well

```
select top 2 * from (select top 100 percent * from events order by dates desc) a order by dates desc
```